# Function to get text from PDF attachment in Gmail is not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written the function below. It is supposed to look at emails from a specific sender and save the PDF attachments as Google Doc files, then retrieve the text from the Google Docs and save them as variables. I'm doing all of this because after I successfully complete this task, I will need to parse text and put some of the info into a spreadsheet.

My function does not return any errors, and it is not logging the google doc text to the console. I checked my Holding Folder and there's nothing it it. I've confirmed that my holding folder ID is correct, and also the sender email is correct, but I'm just not getting anything at all. What could I be doing wrong?

```
function parsePDFs () {

  const senderEmail = "SENDER@EMAIL.COM";
  const holdingFolderId = "FOLDERID";
  const holdingFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(holdingFolderId);

  const threads = GmailApp.search('from:' + senderEmail);
  console.log(threads.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    const thread = threads[i];
    const messages = thread.getMessages();

    for (let j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      const message = messages[j];
      const attachments = message.getAttachments();

      for (let k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
        const attachment = attachments[k];

        if (attachment.getContentType() === "application/pdf") {
          const pdfBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
          const pdfName = "New PDF";

          try {
            const docFile = holdingFolder.createFile(pdfBlob.setName(pdfName));
            const doc = DocumentApp.openById(docFile.getId());
            const docText = doc.getBody().getText();

            console.log("PDF file: " + pdfName);
            console.log("Google Doc Text: " + docText);
          } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error processing attachment: " + pdfName + ", Error: " + error);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

In this case, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

#### From:

```
const docFile = holdingFolder.createFile(pdfBlob.setName(pdfName));
const doc = DocumentApp.openById(docFile.getId());
```

#### To:

```
const docFile = Drive.Files.insert({ title: pdfName, parents: [{ id: holdingFolderId }], mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS }, pdfBlob);
const doc = DocumentApp.openById(docFile.id);
```

- In your script, the PDF blob is created as a file. In your situation, I thought that you might have wanted to convert the PDF format to Google Document. So, I proposed the above modification.
- But, in this modification, it supposes that your PDF data is valid PDF data. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference

- [Method: files.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/files/insert)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tanaike. I made this update and I also changed the triple equality to double equality in the if statement but for some reason, nothing is happening and I am not seeing anything in either the console or the holding folder. When I log attachments.length, I get the output of 1, so I know something is in there

Comment: @Borgher Thank you for replying. About `I made this update and I also changed the triple equality to double equality in the if statement but for some reason, nothing is happening`, `attachment.getContentType()` returns string value. So, when `attachment.getContentType()` is `application/pdf`, I think that `attachment.getContentType() === "application/pdf"` is `true`. I think that your script for this part has no issue.

Comment: @Borgher And, from `When I log attachments.length, I get the output of 1, so I know something is in there`, I'm worried that your attachment file might not be the PDF data or it has no mimeType of `application/pdf`. How about this? For example, please confirm the mimeType of the attachment file by putting `console.log(attachment.getContentType())` just after the line of `const attachment = attachments[k]`. By this, the mimeType of your attachment file can be seen in the log.  I would like to think of the next modification from the result.

Comment: @Borgher By the way, in your current situation, you have already reflected my proposed modification in your script. Is my understanding correct? Unfortunately, I couldn't confirm it from your reply. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Borgher And also, when I tested your script, which reflected my proposed modified script, using an email attached a PDF file, I confirmed that Google Document is created in the folder. From this situation, I'm worried that in your situation, the mimeType of the attachment file might not be `application/pdf`. So, I would like to recommend confirming the mimeType of the attachment file.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the suggestion! Yes, when I tried to log attachment.getContentType(), this is what I get: application/octet-stream. I will try to update the rest of my script to reflect this so I can try to parse this attachment.

Comment: I updated my script to state if (attachment.getContentType() === "application/octet-stream") and I was successful in parsing the data. Thank you Tanaike!

Comment: @Borgher @Borgher Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your reply, I guess that the mimeType of the attachment file is not the PDF type. So, for example, if you want to check the mimeType like `if (attachment.getContentType() === "application/pdf")`, how about modifying `const attachment = attachments[k];` to `const attachment = attachments[k].setContentTypeFromExtension()`? This gives the mimeType using the extension of the filename. But, I'm not sure about the extension of your actual attachment file. So, if this was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not receiving any console output at all, that probably means your script is not entering the if condition.
Try swapping the strict equality (===) to a loose equality (==), and, to prevent other unexpected errors, add a console.log showing the thread/message/attachment name as the first action of each nested loop to make sure your script is progressing as expected, and post your results.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).